# Error: libfdk_aac must be installed

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

Hi I am trying to compile ffmpeg but this error shows:

```
☁  ffmpeg [master] ./configure --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree \
--enable-postproc --enable-libass \
--enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype \
--enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb \
--enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg \
--enable-openssl --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libtheora \
--enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx \
--enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --prefix=/usr
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
ERROR: libfdk_aac must be installed and version must be >= 3.4.12.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.
```

I am simply following this compilation guide: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/MacOSXCompilationGuide

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First try

```
brew install fdk-aac
```

Failing that you can compile like I do

```
git clone git://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac
cd fdk-aac
autoreconf -i
./configure
make install
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/47e59a6/install-ffmpeg.sh)

Comment: Thanks Steven for this

Answer (score 22):

You can install ffmpeg with that encoding library like so:

`brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac`

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work anymore :( https://discourse.brew.sh/t/cannot-get-ffmpeg-to-compile-with-libfdk-aac-mild-panic-setting-in/4031/7

Comment: As far as I can glean from this issue on github, the option was removed but added back again. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/36327#issuecomment-458146095

Answer (score 13):

## [homebrew-ffmpeg](https://github.com/homebrew-ffmpeg/homebrew-ffmpeg)

A few FFmpeg contributors and community members created a new Homebrew tap*, [homebrew-ffmpeg](https://github.com/homebrew-ffmpeg/homebrew-ffmpeg), that includes many options. This is in response to the removal of options from the core Homebrew FFmpeg formulae.

1. Uninstall `ffmpeg` you installed it from Homebrew core:

   ```
   brew uninstall ffmpeg
   ```
2. Enable the repository:

   ```
   brew tap homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg
   ```
3. View available options (optional):

   ```
   brew options homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg
   ```
4. Install `ffmpeg` with the libfdk-aac AAC encoder:

   ```
   brew install homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --HEAD
   ```

See [homebrew-ffmpeg](https://github.com/homebrew-ffmpeg/homebrew-ffmpeg) and [FFmpeg Wiki: macOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS) for more info.

<sub>* Note that this tap is not from the FFmpeg Project itself.</sub>